# When using airflow I get "UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork" + best practice tips to instantiate mongo client in python

Tags: python, mongodb, singleton

I have created a python flow that executes various steps. I also use MongoDB which for now is used for config purposes but will further use it for persistence.
When I execute my code from Pycharm all is good but when I executed it through Airflow I get the fork warning "UserWarning: MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only after forking.".

At first I thought that the problem is that I open many instances of the Mongo client so I used the singleton pattern so that the connection is instantiated only once -please see code below-.
The only way to get rid of the warning is by adding connect=False parameter as you may see commented in my code, but it seems to be a workaround and not a steady solution --according to documentation-.

So what is the problem here? It has something to do with Airflow maybe -since I am not using the mongo_hook-?
In addition please let me know if using the singleton pattern to instantiate once the Mongo Client is a good practice? The client is getting called from various modules.

Note that Mongo as well as Airflow are running in separate dockers.

def singleton(class_):
instances = {}

```
def get_instance(*args, **kwargs):
    if class_ not in instances:
        instances[class_] = class_(*args, **kwargs)
    return instances[class_]

return get_instance
```

@singleton
class MongoPersistence(Persistence):

```
def __init__(self, driver, host, user, password, port, db):
    self._uri = '{driver}://{host}:{port}'.format(driver=driver, host=host, port=port)        
    self._client = MongoClient(self._uri
                         , serverSelectionTimeoutMS=3000  # 3 second timeout
                         , username=self.user
                         , password=self.password
                         # ,connect=False
                               )

    def find_one(self, **kwargs):
    return self._client[kwargs.get('db_name')][kwargs.get('collection_name')].find_one(kwargs.get('query'))
```

Thank you,
Dina

Comment: What is airflow and what documentation are you following?

Comment: Airflow is platform that allows for scheduling and monitoring data workflows written in Python (https://airflow.apache.org/). The documentation I was referring to is the mongodb according to which "Care must be taken when using instances of MongoClient with fork(). Specifically, instances of MongoClient must not be copied from a parent process to a child process."  But I have (since I used the singleton pattern) one Mongo Client and all modules are sharing the same.

Comment: Okay, so is there documentation for this persistence class you are using that tells you how you are supposed to work with it?